# Number of ways of expressing a weight as a sum of positive roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let L be a semisimple Lie algebra over complex field, $H$ be its CSA, and  $\Phi^+=\{\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_N\}$ be its positive roots.

For any weight $\mu\in H^*$, let $\mathfrak{P}(\mu)$ be the number of ways of expressing $\mu$ as a sum of positive roots. That is to say, $\mathfrak{P}(\mu)$ is the numbers of vectors $(r_1,\dots,r_N)$ with $r_i \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ such that $\mu=r_1\beta_1+\cdots+\beta_N$. The function $\mathfrak{P}$ is known as the *Kostant partition function*.

Here is the question:

> Consider the case when L is simple, and $\mu$ be its longest root. Is there a general formula for calculating $\mathfrak{P}(\mu)$ ?

---

For type $A_l$, it's easy to check that $\mathfrak{P}(\mu)=2^{l-1}$.

For type $D_l$, I get the following result using *sagemath*:

> $(l,\mathfrak{P}(\mu)): (3,4), (4,15), (5,55), (6,200), (7,765), (8,2625)$

To find $\mathfrak{P}(\mu)$ in specific case, I use the following property.

> Proposition: *let $\alpha$ be a positive root but not simple, then
> $\alpha$ can be expressed as a sum of two positive roots.*

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that the function $\mathfrak{P}$ is known as the *Kostant partition function*.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner thanks! I did not know it has that name.

Comment: a plausible numberical pattern is that 55=(15-4)*5, 200=(55-15)*5, etc